# Running SSIS package in BIDS 2010

Tags: sql-server, ssis, odbc

I'm  getting the below error  when  ran the SSIS package on  BIDS 2010.I have created the SSIS package on Visual Studio 2015 in my local  and asked to run the package BIDS 2010 in  the server machine which is ran by other team but  we are facing below error can you please check  and let me know

Description: The version of ODBC Source is not compatible with this version of the DataFlow.  End Error  Error: 2016-04-15 10:44:20.73     Code: 0xC0048020     Source: Data Flow Task 10 Data Flow Task 10 (SSIS.Pipeline)     Description: The version of ODBC Source is not compatible with this version of the DataFlow.  End Error  Error: 2016-04-15 10:44:20.74     Code: 0xC0048020     Source: Data Flow Task 11 Data Flow Task 11 (SSIS.Pipeline)

Comment: Of course you do, SSIS is not backwards compatible. With the 2016 release of the data toolings for SSIS, then we'll be able to create SSIS packages for SQL Server 2012, 2014 and 2016. For now though, you *must* match your tooling to database version

Comment: So  i have  develop  again   in VS2010  and ask  them  to  run  in BIDS 2010 correct ? It is not ODBC   version  problem?

Comment: Correct. To run on SQL Server 2012, you need to author with Visual Studio 2010/2012. The error reported specifies "ODBC **Source**", emphasis mine, is incompatible.

Comment: I have developed one package in VS 2012  by  using  SSDT 2012 in my  local  if i  run  this package in Microsoft  SQL  agent  2012 will it run in my QA server ?

Comment: Is QA SQL Server 2012?

Comment: Yes QA  SQL server is  2012

Comment: sir, im  getting the below error while im  running in  the other server   sql agent 2014 but  it is developed in visual  studio 2012 Source: Tickecting Connection manager "APQAL300.wdw"     Description: An ODBC error -1 has occurred.  End Error  Error: 2016-04-28 17:19:26.30     Code: 0xC0014009     Source: Tickecting Connection manager "APQAL300.wdw"     Description: There was an error trying to establish an Open Database Connectivity (ODBC) connection with the database server.  End Error  Error: 2016-04-28 17:19:26.30     Code: 0x0000020F